# conditional beans using spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am trying to write a `ValidatorFactory` which will give me a validator based on its type

```
public Validator getNewValidator(ValidatorType type){

    switch:
         case a : new Validator1();
         break;
          case b : new Validator2();
        break;

}
```

I want to write using spring xml beans definition

I can use method injection but it will let me create only one object and the method does

not take any arguments.

I don't want to use `FactoryBean`.. I am just looking whether we can do this using spring xml

bean definition.

Comment: why don't you want to use FactoryBean?

Comment: there is no reason as such ..i just want to know can is there any way to create conditional beans..just out of curiosity

Comment: This is exactly what `FactoryBean` is for. Don't fight it :)

Comment: I am just looking for an answer is it feasible to do using spring xml bean definition

Answer (score 22):

you can do conditional bean injection with plain xml. The "ref" attribute can be triggered by property values from a property file and thus create conditional beans depending on property values. This feature is not documented but it works perfect.

```
<bean id="validatorFactory" class="ValidatorFactory">
<property name="validator" ref="${validatorType}" />
</bean>

<bean id="validatorTypeOne" class="Validator1" lazy-init="true" />
<bean id="validatorTypeTwo" class="Validator2" lazy-init="true" />
```

And the content of the property file would be:

validatorType=validatorTypeOne

To use the property file in your xml just add this context to the top of your spring config

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:app.properties" />
```

Comment: Just need a little more explanation on how could I do validatorType=validatorTypeOne in XML code?

Comment: validatorType=validatorTypeOne is the content in a property file and the syntax ${validatorType} gets expanded to the value of the property which is in this case: validatorTypeOne. As this points to a bean reference id an instance of the class Validator1 gets created and assigned to the property in ValidatorFactory. Got it?

Comment: No, I am a bit confuse on the statement validatorType=validatorTypeOne. What if I need it to be validatorTypeTwo? And also I got syntax error on ref="${validatorType}". I need some reference on this ref thing so that I can understand it clearly.

Comment: Just be wary of trying this with any beans that use SmartLifecycle. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412628/spring-3-0-lazy-init-not-honoured-for-defaultmessagelistenercontainer) for details.

Answer (score 3):

For complex cases (more complex than the one exposed), [Spring JavaConfig](http://www.springsource.org/javaconfig) could be your friend.

Comment: Before downvoting my answer, please check its date. Spring JavaConfig wasn't very widespread yet in 2010.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using annotation (`@Autowired`, `@Qualifier` etc) instead of xml, you are not able to make conditional beans work (at least at current version 3). This is due to @Qualifier does **not** support expression

```
@Qualifier(value="${validatorType}")
```

More information is at https://stackoverflow.com/a/7813228/418439

Answer (score 1):

I had an slightly different requirements. In my case I wanted to have encoded password in production but plain text in development. Also, I didn't have access to parent bean `parentEncoder`. This is how I managed to achieve that:

```
<bean id="plainTextPassword" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PlaintextPasswordEncoder"/>
<bean id="shaPassword" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
    <constructor-arg type="int" value="256"/>
</bean> 

<bean id="parentEncoder" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean"> 
  <property name="targetSource"> 
    <bean class="org.springframework.aop.target.HotSwappableTargetSource"> 
      <constructor-arg ref="${password.encoding}Password"/> 
    </bean> 
  </property> 
</bean>
```

Of course, I defined `password.encoding` in a property file with possible values as `sha` or `plainText`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
<bean id="myValidator" factory-bean="validatorFactory" factory-method="getNewValidator" scope="prototype">
    <constructor-arg><ref bean="validatorType"/></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="validatorType" ... />
```

Of course, it uses an automatically configured `FactoryBean` underneath but you avoid any Spring dependency in your code.