# Sporadic Auto-Wiring in Spring JMS Message Listener

Tags: java, spring, jms, message-queue, spring-jms

I'm trying to implement a queue for launching jobs via Spring Batch. Queue gets messages for jobs. Processes content and launches the job. Everything works as expected about 50% of the time and I can't tell why.

Here is some code:

```
public class Listener implements MessageListener {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Listener.class);


@Resource(name = "job")
Job job;

@Resource
JobLauncher jobLauncher;
/**
 * Method called when message is sent to Queue. Reads messages in FIFO
 * @param message Message pulled from Queue
 */
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {

    log.info("Message received");
    try {
        String jobName = message.getJMSCorrelationID();

        if (jobName.equals("job")) {
            launchJob(message);
        }
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        log.error("Error with queued message: " + message.toString());
    }
```

What appears to be happening is that sometimes the @Resource's do not get initalized. If I debug, I notice that roughly half of the time they are null, and the other half of the time they are appropriately wired. Proper scanning is coded into the context xml files.

Here is the configuration for the Queue:

```
<!--  Embedded ActiveMQ Broker -->
<amq:broker id="broker" useJmx="false" persistent="false" >
    <amq:transportConnectors>
        <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:0" />
    </amq:transportConnectors>
</amq:broker>

<!--  ActiveMQ Destination  -->
<amq:queue id="destination" physicalName="org" />

<!-- JMS ConnectionFactory to use, configuring the embedded broker using XML -->
<amq:connectionFactory id="jmsFactory" brokerURL="vm://localhost" />

<!-- JMS Producer Configuration -->
<bean id="jmsProducerConnectionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory"
      depends-on="broker"
      p:targetConnectionFactory-ref="jmsFactory" />

<bean id="localQueueTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate"
      p:connectionFactory-ref="jmsProducerConnectionFactory"
      p:defaultDestination-ref="destination" />

<!--JMS Consumer Configuration-->
<bean id="jmsConsumerConnectionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory"
      depends-on="broker"
      p:targetConnectionFactory-ref="jmsFactory" />

<jms:listener-container container-type="default"
                        connection-factory="jmsConsumerConnectionFactory"
                        acknowledge="auto"
                        >
    <jms:listener destination="org" ref="Queue" />
</jms:listener-container>

<bean id="Queue" class="org.Listener" />
```

I've found others SO that might be it. Apparently there is issues with bean creation in listeners due to the different context lifestyles of Listeners beans vs standard Spring Beans. See  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412628/spring-3-0-lazy-init-not-honoured-for-defaultmessagelistenercontainer). However there isn't really a solution. And the only solution suggested I can't seem to get implemented using the jms: namespace.

EDIT:

<s>I've moved some of the configuration contexts around. I've moved the Listener to its own context file. Now, the @Resources are initialized exactly once. The first message sent will properly run a job. Every subsequent message seems to have the null launcher and job.</s>

EDIT 2:

<s>I've moved the queue configuration to a context file outside common. This seems to have fixed the issue.</s>

It appears, based on the debugger, that multiple instances of the Listener are being instantiated. Some get properly wired whereas some do not. This seems to have to do with the order with which this instances are being instantiated. Moving the context around most likely means that the beans are available when the Listener is being created.

As such, it seems that I merely need to add a dependency to the Queue bean, so that it "depends-on" the job and job launcher. I will give this a shot and hopefully report back.

EDIT 3:

<s>It appears the "depends-on" does not work as intended. I have opted for the solution of moving the Queue Logic to a different configuration context. This context imports all resources for the job. Every object instantiated (there are two for some reason) is properly wired.</s>

EDIT 4:

The issue was caused by multiple loadings of the context file. As an example, here was the issue located in a web.xml file

```
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Job1 Controller</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>controller-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Job1 Controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Job1/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Job2 Controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>controller-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Job2 Controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Job2/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: What you are describing makes no sense; the referenced question is entirely unrelated (it's about lifecycle causing eager instantiation of the `DMLC`). "every subsequent message..." - impossible - the same listener instance is used for all messages so one it's wired up, it has the same deps for every message. I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework` - it emits copious wiring messages.

Comment: @GaryRussell Based on the debugger there are multiple listeners instances being made. I've reverted back to the 50% configuration. It appears there are at default 3 listener objects. 2 are properly wired. 1 is not. I assume this means that multiple beans are being made amongst the various context files.

Comment: @GaryRussell It appears I've managed something by moving the configuration to a different context file. I can't determine why there are multiple listener objects being instantiated but based upon debugging there appears to be at least two. However after the move all objects are wired correctly.

Comment: DEBUG logging should show you why you are getting multiple instances.

Comment: @GaryRussell The debug statements are less than helpful. There are exactly two instances of "Creating instance of bean 'Queue'". It seems every bean defined in the ams and jms namespace gets exactly two instances. There only exists one configuration for the queue amongst all the context files. Do the debug files tell me why a certain bean is been instantiated?

Comment: You can't have two instances of the same bean name in the same context - the second bean definition wins. This implies to me you have the bean declared in multiple contexts. Further up the log you should see which files are parsed. Is this a web app? A common mistake is to load the same context in the root context (`ContextLoadedListener`) as well as the servlet's context.

Comment: @GaryRussell That is not the case. The context is only being loaded in one place.

Comment: Like I said; it's impossible to get 2 instances with the same bean name. So something is amiss in your analysis.

Comment: @GaryRussell Is there any indication in the log files as to why or what is initializing certain beans? Like what context file it is being evoked from? I can assure you there is only one instance of the above configuration in every context file in the project.

Comment: @GaryRussell Could the two instances have anything to do with the dynamic scaling capabilities of DMLC? From what I've read the Listener Container initializes as many concurrent listeners as it is allowed to have at minimum. However it also appears that the default would be 1 for DMLC.

Comment: @GaryRussell Looks like you were correct. We are loading the context twice. I was not aware but in our web.xml we are creating two sets of controllers using the same context files. Sorry if I seemed a bit aloof but I'm quite new to Spring. Thank you for your help. Sorry I also couldn't move this to chat. No rep.