# Spring Qualifier and property placeholder

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Does anyone know if I should be able to use property placeholder as an expression in a Qualifier? I can't seem to get this working.

I am using spring 3.0.4.

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("${service.class}")
   Service service;
}

@Service
@Qualifier("ServiceA")
ServiceA implements Service {
   public void print() {
       System.out.println("printing ServiceA.print()");
   } 
}

@Service
@Qualifier("ServiceB")
ServiceB implements Service {
   public void print() {
      System.out.println("printing ServiceB.print()");
   } 
}
```

XML:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="file:/etc/config.properties"/>
</bean>
```

config.properties:

```
config.properties
service.class=serviceB
```

Comment: what would be the point of doing this in a properties file and with `@Qualifier` when you could just choose how to wire the bean up in the XML instead?

Comment: Have you looked at spring-3 profile beans? It seems like that might be what you're looking for. It does seem like you should be able to do what you're asking, since spring-3 has @Value annotations that support resolving properties. But I just don't know for sure.

Comment: @matt Just Wanted to minimize the use of XML. And property file because different deployments will use different implementations.

Answer (score 41):

This works.  You can leave off the service names if you just use the default spring bean name.  serviceA vs ServiceA, etc.

```
@Controller
class MyController {
@Autowired(required=false)
@Qualifier("Service")
Service service;

public static void main(String[] args) {
   ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("app-ctx.xml", MyController.class);
   for(String s:context.getBeanDefinitionNames()){
       System.out.println(s);
       for(String t:context.getAliases(s)){
           System.out.println("\t" + t);
       }
   }
   context.getBean(MyController.class).service.print();
  }
}

public interface Service {
    void print();
}

@Service(value="ServiceA")
public class ServiceA implements example.Service {
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("printing ServiceA.print()");
    } 
}

@Service(value="ServiceB")
public class ServiceB implements example.Service {
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("printing ServiceB.print()");
    } 
}
```

XML:

```
<beans>
    <alias name="${service.class}" alias="Service"/>
    <context:property-placeholder location="example/app.properties"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="example"/>
<beans>
```

Props:

```
service.class=ServiceB
```

Comment: Dunno why this has not been accepted. It is definetly the neatest way to do what the OP wanted. +1

Comment: Is there any reason why you added `required="false"` on the `@Autowired` annotation?

Comment: I just tried it and did not use `required="false"`. Works as well. It's actually quite neat. The only thing I was missing was: `<alias name="${service.class}" alias="Service"/>` and that did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to do this without the xml, just annotations?

Comment: This works without XML: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107133/spring-bean-alias-in-javaconfig/28988342#28988342

Comment: Working solution without XML: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47074088/2442133

Answer (score 22):

This solution works without XML and with properties file.

Yours classes improved:

`MyController.java`:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    public MyController(@Qualifier("MyServiceAlias") MyService myService) {
        myService.print();
    }
}
```

`ServiceA.java`:

```
@Service("serviceA")
public class ServiceA implements MyService {
    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("printing ServiceA.print()");
    }
}
```

`ServiceB.java`:

```
@Service("serviceB")
public class ServiceB implements MyService {
    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("printing ServiceB.print()");
    }
}
```

`application.properties` (here you can change which class will be loaded):

```
service.class=serviceA
```

And important configuration file `AppConfig.java`:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Bean
    public MyService MyServiceAlias(@Value("${service.class}") String qualifier) {
        return (MyService) context.getBean(qualifier);
    }
}
```

---

Additional explanations:

- Use `@Qualifier` only for field which will be autowired. For services, to specify bean name, use `@Service`.
- If you want standard bean name you don't need to use `@Service` with specyify name. For example, standard bean name for ServiceA is `serviceA` (not `ServiceA` - see big first letter), so `@Service("serviceA")` redundant (`@Service` is enough).
- I based `AppConfig` on this answer: [Spring Bean Alias in JavaConfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107133/spring-bean-alias-in-javaconfig/28988342#28988342).
- This solution is better than this [Spring Qualifier and property placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812745/spring-qualifier-and-property-placeholder/12715752#12715752), because you don't need XML.
- Tested on Spring Boot 1.5.7.

Answer (score 4):

I would venture to guess the answer is no, just based on the write ups in a few javadoc pages. For example, see the docs for `@Value`:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html

Notice they make special mention of using expressions in the annotation. For comparison, the docs for `@Qualifier`:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html

Which make no mention of expressions. Obviously not a definitive answer (but spring is generally very good on documentation). Also, if expressions were supported in the `@Qualifier` annotation I would expect they work the same way as the `@Value` annotation (just based on spring being a very consistent framework).

Spring 3.1 has the new profile bean feature, which seems like it can accomplish something like what you're trying to do. Here's a write up for that:

http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/

Answer (score 2):

As a workarround, you can set the desired Spring service implementation based on its name in your config.properties.

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
  //add a String which will hold the name of the service to implement
  @Value("${service.class}")
  private String serviceToImplement;

  Service service;

  // now autowire spring service bean based on int name using setter
  @Autowired
  public void setService(ApplicationContext context) {
    service = (Service) context.getBean(serviceToImplement);
   }
}

@Service
 @Qualifier("ServiceA")
 ServiceA implements Service {
  public void print() {
   System.out.println("printing ServiceA.print()");
  } 
}

 @Service
 @Qualifier("ServiceB")
 ServiceB implements Service {
   public void print() {
    System.out.println("printing ServiceB.print()");
   } 
}
```

config.properties

```
service.class=serviceB
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use **@ConditionalOnProperty**.
If you don't need to use both of those services in one context, then your code could be something like:

```
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(value="storage.type", havingValue = "serviceA")
ServiceA implements Service {
   public void print() {
       System.out.println("printing ServiceA.print()");
   } 
}

@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(value="service.class", havingValue = "serviceB")
ServiceB implements Service {
   public void print() {
      System.out.println("printing ServiceB.print()");
   } 
}

@Controller
public class MyController {
   @Autowired
   Service service;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Maybe give this a whirl:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

   private String serviceId;

   @Value("${serviceId}")
   public void setServiceId(String serviceId) {
      this.serviceId = serviceId;
   }

   @Autowired
   @Qualifier(serviceId)
   Service service;
}
```

Comment: @Aaron http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html Annotations consist of an at-sign (@) followed by an annotation type and a parenthesized list of element-value pairs. The values must be compile-time constants So the workaround with an instance String will not work course of a compile error ....