# autowire a Spring bean based on the value of a property

Tags: spring, properties, dependency-injection

nI am developing a Spring MVC web app using Spring 3.2. We will deploy the web app to different customers. Each customer may use one of several implementations of a service interface.

It's possible that the customer may need to reset these values, so we can't just hard-wire the implementation into the application, it needs to be externally configurable.
We are already using customer-specific property files that for setting simple properties such as Strings, numbers etc, but I'm asking how to set a particular implementation of an interface.

E.g.,

```
class MyClass {
 // this is straightforward
 @Value("${customer.propertyInPropertyFile}")
 private String customerSpecificString;

 // how to set the correct implementation for each customer?
 private ISomeService service;

}
```

If there are 4 implementations of ISomeService, we can't autowire, or explicitly set a bean, as this will then be set in the compiled code - and it needs to be configurable after the application is deployed ( it would be OK to restart the application though if need be)..

Does anyone know how to do this? Would this better be performed using  Spring EL, or profiles?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring Qualifier and property placeholder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812745/spring-qualifier-and-property-placeholder)

Comment: also take a look at [spring profiles](https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/).

Comment: I had a look at the first link, this is using aliases and XML configuration. I was hoping to use Java annotation configuration but perhaps this is impossible since annotation values are compile-time constants. Things are complicated by the fact that in our Spring config file, the same ${} notation also identifies variables replaced during Maven build, so will need to figure out how to distinguish properties that are replaced at compile time ad build time.

Answer (score -1):

So, as I wanted to used Java configuration, I used the following solution:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("prod")
@EnableAsync
public class ProductionConfig extends BaseConfig
// inject property value which identifies theimplementation to use
Value("${service.impl}")
private String serviceName;

@Bean()

    public IRepository repository() {
        IRepository rc = null;
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(serviceName)){
            rc =  new Impl1();
        } else if ("sword-mets".equals(serviceName)){
            rc = new Impl2();
        } else {
            rc = new Impl3();
        }
        log.info("Setting in repository implementation " + rc);
        return rc;

    }
```

So, this isn't quite as clean as the suggested reply using aliases - the Config class needs to know about all the possible implementation classes - but is  simple and avoids having to use the XML config just for this bean.

Comment: when you create objects explicitly using new keyword instead of beanfactory the wiring inside those objects will not happen.