# Aliasing a bean outside the bean definition using Java config in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

How to alias a bean outside the bean definition using Java config in Spring Boot?

Comment: ''outside the bean definition" do you mean, bean is already defined and you are not allowed to change that?

Comment: @AtulDwivedi The bean is already defined in another project(jar) and I'm using it in my project, now I have a requirement to alias the same bean.

Answer (score 6):

I have this as well, and solved it like this:

```
@Component
public class AliasConfiguration implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        beanFactory.registerAlias("originalBeanName", "newAlias");
        beanFactory.registerAlias("originalBeanName", "newAlias2");
        beanFactory.registerAlias("otherOriginalBeanName", "newAlias3");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to alias a bean which is already defined somewhere else, **this feature is not supported in spring yet.**

Along with that aliasing a bean is not allowed in `@Component`, `@Service` and `@Repository`.

Either you can alias a bean while defining in XML configuration or while using `@Bean(name = {"alias1", "alias2"})`. But as you mentioned in you case bean is already defined in another JAR, it's not possible to alias it.

A similar(not exactly similar) [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/11402) is open to `spring-framework`.