# How to name @Component from properties file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using spring. I know how to use properties data inside a class but I need to know how to give component name from the properties file.

```
@Component("componentName") // here I need to give my property instead of "componentName".
public class TestClass {

}
```

I do search abt it but not able to find sos! Please help me...

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you want to do this, could you clarify?

Comment: I think you can find answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812745/spring-qualifier-and-property-placeholder

Comment: for reusability for next projects.We can easily change the prop name in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid that is not possible. All names that is given to `@Controller`, `@Service` and so on requires to be final/constant.

Comment: Yes finally got to know its not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use additional XML config, use alias directive as explained [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812745/spring-qualifier-and-property-placeholder):

```
<beans>
    <alias name="${service.class}" alias="Service"/>
    <context:property-placeholder location="example/app.properties"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="example"/>
<beans>
```

If you need to use java config only, there's an open issue about it [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6736). It is still unresolved, so for strictly java config the same is not currently possible.

If that's a problem, you can also register a bean programmatically as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540713/add-bean-programmatically-to-spring-web-app-context). So you'd autowire a property and your target bean, implement [BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.html) and register your bean in the registry you get as a parameter using your property.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, from Spring 3 or up, you can use 
**@PropertySource** annotation to externalize your configuration to a properties file. And then display the values with **@Value**

If you are talking about distinguishing configuration beans, @Qualifier is the thing you are looking for