# Is it possible to load a Bean using Autowire, specifing the bean name in the application.properties file?

Tags: java, spring-boot

So i have GamerRunner Class were i want to inject a GameConsole Object using a BeanName that is specified in the applicaiton.properties file

```
@Component
public class GameRunner {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("${game.component}")
    private GameConsole game;

    public void run(){
        game.up();
        game.down();
        game.left();
        game.right();
    }

}
```

The application.properties file would have this line

```
game.component=mario
```

And i have 2 components that implement the GameConsole

```
@Component("mario")
public class MarioGame implements GameConsole{
    @Override
    public void up(){
        System.out.println("jump");
    }
    @Override
    public void down(){
        System.out.println("down into a hole");
    }
    @Override
    public void left(){
        System.out.println("stop");
    }
    @Override
    public void right(){
        System.out.println("accelerate");
    }

}
```

```
@Component("pacman")
public class PacManGame implements GameConsole {
    @Override
    public void up(){
        System.out.println("PacMan up");
    }
    @Override
    public void down(){
        System.out.println("PacMan down");
    }
    @Override
    public void left(){
        System.out.println("PacMan left");
    }
    @Override
    public void right(){
        System.out.println("PacMan right");
    }
}
```

The GameRunner is unable to inject the specified bean.

Is this even possible?

I found a solution to this problem but i don't use qualifier.
I do the following steps:
Is there another way to do this or is this the only way right now.

1. Get bean name from the application.properties file
2. Get the bean from the applicationContext
3. Pass the bean to the GameRunner Class

Below is the solution which i got from this link:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812745/spring-qualifier-and-property-placeholder#:~:text=Use%20%40Qualifier%20only%20for%20field%20which%20will%20be,letter%29%2C%20so%20%40Service%20%28%22serviceA%22%29%20redundant%20%28%40Service%20is%20enough%29](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812745/spring-qualifier-and-property-placeholder#:%7E:text=Use%20%40Qualifier%20only%20for%20field%20which%20will%20be,letter%29%2C%20so%20%40Service%20%28%22serviceA%22%29%20redundant%20%28%40Service%20is%20enough%29).

```
@Configuration

public class GameConfiguration {
   @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;
   @Bean("gameRunner")
   GameRunner GameRunnerAlias(@Value("${game.component}") String game){
       return new GameRunner((GameConsole)context.getBean(game));
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The Javadoc of `@Qualifier`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) doesn't mention use of Spring EL would be allowed.

#### Conditional beans

However, you can use conditional beans to only create the bean if the property is set using [`@ConditionalOnProperty`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html):

```java
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="game.component", havingValue="mario")
public class MarioGame implements GameConsole{
    //...
}
```

```java
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="game.component", havingValue="pacman")
public class PacmanGame implements GameConsole{
    //...
}
```

This way, a `MarioGame` bean would be created if and only if `game.component` was set to `mario`.
Similarly, a `PacmanGame` bean would be created if and only if `game.component` was set to `pacman`.

Then, you only have a single `GameConsole` bean and don't need `@Qualifier`.

#### Register it under a different name

If you do want both beans to be instantiated, you can register the "correct" one once more under a different name:

```java
@Bean("gameConsole")
public GameConsole console(ApplicationContext ctx, @Value("${game.component}") String componentName){
    return (GameConsole)ctx.getBean(componentName);
}
```

In that case, you can use `@Qualifier` to get that bean:

```java
@Qualifier("gameConsole")
private GameConsole game;
```